# How to create a LIFO Queue Channel

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-integration

Currently I am using a Queue Channel in my Integration flow but it uses a FIFO way of extraction. Is there a way to change it to LIFO?

Also, is there a way to remove messages from the Queue based on a property?

I suspect I will need to use a PriorityChannel for switching from FIFO to LIFO but I can't figure out how it would be accomplished.

```
@Bean
    fun notificationChannel(): MessageChannel {
        return MessageChannels.queue().get()
    }
```

For example, my QueueChannel will be filled with messages containing userId. Since I'm only interested in the latest state of the userId message I want to use LIFO and remove all messages with the same userId as the latest message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't really want LIFO, you just want the latest for a given condition.

But, regardless, `Queue` is a pretty simple interface; it only has a handful of methods and the `QueueChannel` only uses `poll()`, `offer()` and `size()`.

So it should be simple to create a custom queue, e.g. based on a thread-safe `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Message<?>>` with the key being your condition.

Comment: How would I have to proceed so that the older messages with the same userId in the queue are discarded?

Comment: If it's based on a `Map`, new entries with the same key will be replaced and it will only have the last one.

Comment: If you want to retain order for different userIds, you can use a combination of a `LinkedHashSet<String>` for the userIds and `Map<String, Message<?>>` for the messages. The `LinkedHashSet` retains the original order when an element is replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Queue channel takes Queue as a constructor parameter `public QueueChannel(Queue<Message<?>> queue)` and spring-integration DSL provides `public static QueueChannelSpec queue(Queue<Message<?>> queue)`. So you can use `Collections.asLifoQueue(..)` as an argument to the above factory method to get the behavior you want.